# What are the MySQL Tables Count Vs Performance Issues

Tags: mysql, database, performance, wordpress, database-design

I have a doubt regarding the number of mysql tables vs performance.

I'm running a WordPress with MultiSite feature. 
In this 9 new tables where create on each site creation. 
So if i have 1000 site in single WordPress Multisite, then the total number of tables become 9000.

My Question is : Is the number of table will affect the performance of the MySQL Database???

Comment: http://serverfault.com/questions/83438/have-too-many-tables-in-a-mysql-database-can-affect-performance

Answer (score 0):

From what I have heard, once the install gets beyond 2,000 or so sites, there will be issues.  If you plan on having a lot of sites running you should look into WP Multisite scaling issues such as multi DB provisioning.  This is a paid plugin that helps with that: http://premium.wpmudev.org/project/multi-db

Answer (score 0):

The biggest problem you'll face will be memory related restrictions - as your server runs out of memory to retain each database table/php instance in memory, your server will start to thrash the disks - much like when you have low memory on your home PC and the disk starts thrashing as virtual memory is used.

Give it a lot of memory and it should be fine.

WPMUDev have great plugins for optimising and improving multisite installations, including [splitting multi-site installs out into separate databases](http://premium.wpmudev.org/project/multi-db/?ref=dhilditch-00137) to overcome any MySQL performance problems.